# vue bootstrap toaster instantly vanishing / hiding itself

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

In my Vue Bootstrap (v2.21.2) Web-App i want to use Toasts to present some errors to the user. Those errors are produced by the REST-API-client. In my vb-components i catch those errors and call a function which itself uses https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/toast#toasts-on-demand `this.$bvToast.toast()` to dynamically create and show the error-message.
As expected the toast is created but will instantly hide itself again. I tried disabling the auto-hide property and play around with the timeout which had no effect. Since i am calling this function in some sub-components i also tried calling `this.$root.$bvToaster.toast()` but the toasts are still only showing for some 100 microseconds or so.

The relevant (reduced) code-extracts of my project:

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navbar @viewChanged="view = $event;" />
    <Pki v-if="view == 'pki'" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.vue";
import Pki from './components/Certificates'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      view: null
    }
  },
  name: "FooBar",
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Pki
  },
};
</script>
```

Certificates.vue:

```
<template>
    <!-- ... -->
</template>

<script>
    // ...
    mounted() {
      this.getCertificates();
    },
    methods: {
      alert(title, content, variant = 'danger') {
        this.$bvToast.toast(content, {
          title: title,
          toaster: 'b-toaster-bottom-right',
          variant: variant,
          solid: true,
          appendToast: true,
          autoHideDelay: 10000
        });
      },
      getCertificates() {
        axios.get("/v1/pki/certificates")
        .then((response) => {
             // ...
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.alert('API Error', 'failed to fetch certificate list (' + error.message + ')');
          console.log('getCertificates(): HTTP ERROR ' + error.response.status + ' (' + error.response.data + ')');
        });
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you importing Bootstrap **AND** BootstrapVue CSS into your project? I'd also double check which version of Bootstrap you've installed.

Comment: Ah yes i do actually. I don't know why though. I initially created the project skeleton with vue-cli.

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.css';

Comment: Might've worded my question poorly. You should be importing both, so what you have appears to be correct. Next would be checking the version of Bootstrap you've installed.

Comment: Gotcha. Thx for the clarification. Regarding bootstrap-version my package.json defines the following:

    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",

Comment: BootstrapVue doesn't officially support Bootstrap `4.6.0`, so you could try downgrading to `4.5.3` instead. Though, I don't think that will fix it. I tested your `alert` method on the docs [playground](https://bootstrap-vue.org/play) and looked to work there.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using bootstrap 5 just add this css

```
.toast:not(.show) {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: this work me. tks

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't have the appropriate version of the bootstrap css.

e.g 4.5.3 bootstrap css
and after load the vue bootstrap

Had the same issue, and this solved it

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you sure? https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs defines the following versions: "Vue.js v2.6 is required, v2.6.12 is recommended", "Bootstrap v4.3.1 is required, v4.5.3 is recommended", "BootstrapVue release v2.21.2."
I tried both bootstrap 4.6.0 and 4.5.3, but it didn't change anything

Comment: I have the following:
Head
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css"/>
Bottom
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

and it works fine now.